# Clean url rewriting using .htacces file in apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website where i do blogging... on my blog.php page i have posts from different categories.
when a user clicks on a link it is being redirect to /blog-details.php page with `$_GET['title']` variable.

what I have tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#remove .php from all pages
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

#blog/title-here
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ /blog-details.php?title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

last line gives me something like

> xyz.com/blog-details?title=hello-world

what i want to achieve is

> xyz.com/blog/hello-world

not like

> xyz.com/blog-details?title=hello-world

thank you, looking forward to answers.

Comment: Welcome. What you want and what you tried differs, do you want `blog/` to be in the url or not? Also, linking to `/blog-details.php?title=XYZ` will not "redirect"/"rewrite" the URL, you'd need to link to `/blog/XYZ`

Comment: /blog would be fine though like xyz.com/blog/title-here, thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Have you tried using a title that doesn't contain any "special" characters like the `-` in your example? Does changing to `[A-Za-z0-9\-\+]` work? (Changed `-` to `\-`) Is your Apache set up to read `.htaccess` files? Is `mod_rewrite` installed/enabled?

Comment: yes i have tried it and ``` mod-rewrite ``` is also enabled, it is still giving me blog-details?title=hello-world

Comment: "_it is still giving me blog-details?title=hello-world_" What does that mean? `blog-details?title=hello-world` is _not_ rewritten to `/blog/hello-world`, that's still a valid url as mentioned in my comment. Does `/blog/hello-world` work?

Comment: I mean when i click read more link from blog.php page , the url doesn't change , it is same as it was ```blog-details?title=hello-world``` all i want is ```/blog/hello-world```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important thing you have to take into consideration when working with .htaccess files, is that you have to check if the path is a directory or file, then proceed to do your action.

I used your code and it worked properly, but simply added the -f and -d checks to make sure that this does not affect other pages.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#remove .php from all pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

#blog/title-here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ /blog-details.php?title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

To test out your .htaccess file and with some dummy URLs, I'd highly recommend you to check out MadeWithLove

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

This will let you have a test input URL and see if you get the proper output URL (the actual URL your server would read).

---

With that being said, I would recommend you to look into routing for future projects and self-development. A framework I'd recommend checking out is fat-free framework (f3) for PHP. It's very easy to get into, you could learn it in 2 days, and it saves a lot of time in development - by containing routing, ORM, global variables, simplified SQL queries, and plenty of other features that essentially keep you a PHP developer, rather than a framework developer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using xampp and i turned on ```loadModule for mod_rewrite ```  Also ```AllowOverride All``` but it is still giving me blog-details?title=hello-world

Comment: @NaikJavaid, try to force refresh your page with Ctrl+Shift+R on a Windows several times (Cmd+Shift+R on a Mac I think), and try again. The links xyz.com/blog/hello-world should properly display xyz.com/blog-details.php?title=hello-world -- if this doesn't work then perhaps you have another redirection in your code someplace else.

Comment: sir, im sending request from blog.php when users clicks read more to blog-details page... ```<a class="post-button" href="blog-details?title=<?php echo htmlentities($row['url'], ENT_QUOTES)?>">Read More</a>``` i have this link in blog.php read more button

Comment: change the href content to "blog/<?php echo htmlentities($row['url'], ENT_QUOTES)?>" and it should work. that way, you would have xyz.com/blog/title-here.. 
I read from your previous comments that you wanted it to display as xyz.com/blog/title-here which is why I'm providing this solution, otherwise you should elaborate more on what you want initially. Though if I'm being honest, this is the standardized way that blogs generally display their content, so I wouldn't recommend thinking of something else

Comment: now it throws 404 after adding ```blog/<?php echo htmlentities($row['url'], ENT_QUOTES)?>``` to the link in ```blog.php`` page. Anyways, thank you for your time @patrickYounes

Comment: I didn't say to add that to the link -- I simply said to change the 'read more' button's link to ```blog/<?php echo htmlentities($row['url'], ENT_QUOTES)?>```
Can you give me the full URL that's giving you error 404?

Comment: this ```<a class="post-button" href="blog-details?title=<?php echo htmlentities($row['url'], ENT_QUOTES)?>">Read More</a>``` is the link on ```blog.php``` page, the details of post are on``` blog-details.php``` page , i tried to change it to  ```blog/<?php echo htmlentities($row['url'], ENT_QUOTES)?>``` and it is throwing 404

Answer (score 0):

use below method:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z_=-]+)$ blog-details.php?title=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Then you can access the title like $_GET['title'] on the page.